# How can I filter images out of HTML Scrapy with XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get the HTML of various articles using Scrapy. These articles also include images that I want to process separately.

If I have an article whose HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="article>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <img src="/path/to/image.jpg"/>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
</div>
```

How can I scrape just the non-image HTML, or this:

```
<div class="article>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
</div>
```

I've currently tried:

```
article = response.xpath("//div[@class='article'][not(img)]").extract()
```

...but this still includes the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XPath is for selection, not transformation or rearrangement.**

You can select the `div` elements that have no `img` children:

```
//div[@class='article' and not(img)]
```

or have no `img` descendents:

```
//div[@class='article' and not(.//img)]
```

Or, you can select the contents of the `div` elements that are `p`:

```
//div[@class='article']/p
```

or that are not `img`:

```
//div[@class='article']/*[not(self::img)]
```

But you cannot select the requested HTML,

```
<div class="article">
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  <p>This is a sentence.</p>
</div>
```

because that is a rearrangement, not a selection, of markup that exists in the input document.

Comment: Got it - that is why the other response (`//div[@class='article']/*[not(self::img)]`) was returning _nothing_ at all...because the articles I'm trying to select have images and that would only select articles that do not have images?

Comment: The XPath you mention in your comment would select all non-image child elements of all article `div` elements.  If it's selecting nothing and surprising you, I'd have to see the HTML to say more.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
article = response.xpath("//div[@class='article']//*[not(self::img)]").extract()
```